# Groupby and Lambda together

Tags: python

Let's say we have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Bins':[(0,10),(11,20), (0,10), (21,30)],
                  'Age':[14,17,18, 15]})
```

```
    Bins        Age
0   (0, 10)     14
1   (11, 20)    17
2   (0, 10)     18
3   (21, 30)    15
```

Now, we want to groupby this data frame on `Bins`, and also powers up the `Age` values and put the results into a new column. Here's the code I use for this purpose:

```
df['New'] = df.groupby('Bins')['Age'].apply(lambda i:np.power(i,2))
```

But the result is not what I expected to see. As it doesn't grouped the results in 3 different bins:

```
Bins         Age     New
0   (0, 10)  14      196
1   (11, 20) 17      289
2   (0, 10)  18      324
3   (21, 30) 15      225
```

Comment: what is the expected result and where is the power applied?

Comment: @urban yes you are right and sorry for not being clear. I was looking for summation of powered values. Thanks to you, I've found it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirement correctly, when you are grouping you have to define what operation you are doing if a bin has multiple values. I think what you meant to do is:

1. groupby()
2. sum() or mean()
3. apply()

Example:

```
In [17]: df.groupby('Bins')['Age'].sum().apply(lambda i:i**2)
Out[17]:
Bins
(0, 10)     1024
(11, 20)     289
(21, 30)     225
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

where `sum()` gives you:

```
In [18]: df.groupby('Bins')['Age'].sum()
Out[18]:
Bins
(0, 10)     32
(11, 20)    17
(21, 30)    15
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

The power is now applied on the result of the sum.

You can replace that with `mean()` if that makes more sense in your case

Comment: Thank you very much urban for your help. Yes I was exactly looking for this and didn't know where should I put .sum() method.